# SQL Server generate INSERTs to copy the records from one server to another

Tags: sql-server

I am using

```
exec sp_generate_inserts 'TABLENAME'
```

to copy all the records of one table from our test server to live server.

Do we have to create the table first before using this command?????

I tried to give this command and it gives me an error - Invalid Object name.

I tried to create the table first and then to give this command. But in that case I have an identity column in the table and it gives an error..... Cannot insert identity value .
I know that the identity insert is set to off. Do I have to turn it on and try....How can turn it on.....And also could you please let me know if we have an alternative way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES of course** you have to create the table first before inserting data into it....

And if you want to insert specific values into an `IDENTITY` column, you can use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT (your table name) ON

-- do your INSERTs here

SET IDENTITY_INSERT (your table name) OFF
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick update....it worked well......Thanks for your support

Comment: Hey do we have any command to generate alter scripts just as we do above for insert